# Assign random text to enemies

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: screen shot]

I'm trying to create a falling word game (code [here](https://github.com/Brackeys/Falling-Words-Typing-Game)). I want the words to be assigned to 3 enemies that spawn from the top of the screen and fall down to the bottom. Here is the enemy script:

```c#
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

public float fallSpeed = 1.0f;    

void Update () {
    transform.Translate(0, -fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Here is the word spawner:

```c#
public class WordSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject wordPrefab;
public GameObject enemy;
public Transform wordCanvas;

public WordDisplay SpawnWord()
{

    Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f), 7.0f, 0);
    GameObject wordObj = Instantiate(wordPrefab, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity, wordCanvas);
    WordDisplay wordDisplay = wordObj.GetComponent<WordDisplay>();
    return wordDisplay;
  }     
}
```

This is the word timer:

```c#
public class Wordimer : MonoBehaviour {

public WordManager wordManager;
public float delay = 1.5f;
private float nextWord = 0f;

void Update()
{
    if (Time.time >= nextWord)
    {
        wordManager.AddWord();
        nextWord = Time.time + delay;
        delay *= 0.95f;
       }
    }
}
```

The AddWord() method in the above script is what generates the word randomly from a list of words. Here is the add word method (this method is in a separate file):

```c#
public void AddWord()
{
    WordDisplay wordDisplay = wordSpawner1.SpawnWord();

    Word word = new Word(WordGenerator.GetRandomWord(), wordDisplay);

    words.Add(word); 
}
```

So what I would like for the words to be spawned along with the enemy game objects. Right now they spawn on their own. How can I achieve this functionality?

**Edit**

This is the script that spawns the enemy:

```c#
public GameObject enemy;
public float spawnTime = 3.0f;
public Transform[] spawnPoints;    

void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
}

void Spawn()
{               
    int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);        
    Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
}
```

Comment: Well, you'd need to know what your enemy's `position` is when you spawn the word. Try passing that data over.

Comment: And what is `randomPosition` for if you want it positioned on the `enemy`?

Comment: @derHugo, I added the postion of the enemy instead of randomPosition. GameObject wordObj = Instantiate(wordPrefab, new Vector3(enemy.transform.position.x, enemy.transform.position.y, 0), Quaternion.identity, wordCanvas); it still doens't show up near the enemy. the words just spawn in the center of the screen now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly what you are trying to achieve is spawning the `WordDisplay` and keep it "next to" the according `enemy` object, the reference you already have in `WordSpawner`.

You could assign it to a certain `Enemy` and let the enemy update the position like

```c#
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float fallSpeed = 1.0f;    

    public WordDisplay assosiatedDisplay;

    // optional for always showing the text e.g. 10 cm above enemies
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0);

    void Update () 
    {
        transform.Translate(0, -fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        if(assosiatedDisplay)
        {
            // keep the referenced wordDisplay positioned relative to this object
            assosiatedDisplay.transform.position = transform.position + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

And than set that `associatedDisplay` value when you spawn the `WordDisplay`

```c#
public class WordSpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject wordPrefab;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public Transform wordCanvas;

    public WordDisplay SpawnWord()
    {
        GameObject wordObj = Instantiate(wordPrefab, enemy.transform.position * new Vector3(1, 1, 0), Quaternion.identity, wordCanvas);
        WordDisplay wordDisplay = wordObj.GetComponent<WordDisplay>();

        // assign it to the enemy
        enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().assosiatedDisplay = wordDisplay;

        return wordDisplay;
   }     
}
```

---

**Update**

I don't see in your question and have no clue where all your methods are called.
But you would store the according `enemy` reference the same way when you instantiate your enemy objects:

```c#
var enemy = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
```

and later pass that `enemy` reference to the `public WordDisplay SpawnWord()` e.g.

```c#
public WordDisplay SpawnWord(Enemy enemy)
{
    // ...

    // assign it to the enemy
    enemy.assosiatedDisplay = wordDisplay;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I get an error with the code: enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>.assosiatedDisplay = wordDisplay ; it says GameObject.GetComponent<T>() is a method, which is not valid in the given context. I want the word to be displayed as floating text of the enemy. something like a healthbar.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the brackets: `GetComponent<Enemy>()`

Comment: thanks. there are no more errors but the words just spawn in the center of the screen. i have embedded the screenshot in the question.

Comment: I noticed another thing. in the enemy prefab, I had dragged the word prefab in the associated display field. Howeer, when I hit play, it says type mismatch in the associated display.

Comment: You shouldn't drag it in via the inspector .. because as you say you than referenced the **prefab**, not the Instantiated object (clone). Where the type missmatch comes from exactly I don't know but basically you can't set a Scene reference to a prefab. Is `enemy` a prefab and not the Instantiated `Enemy` object in the scene?

Comment: the enemy is a prefab. There is a spawn enemy script that instantiates the enemy

Comment: And where is the code for that? Please add all relevant code to your question